# "You are testing actions that you created in project: [[ another project ]]"

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I'm struggling to get a Google [sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-updates-nodejs/issues/4) working.

I think I'm following the instructions correctly but now, when testing (in `project-y`), I receive a warning:

> You are testing the Actions that you have created in project: project-x

I had previously used `project-x` but it has since been deleted. I've tried deleting the project and recreating, redeploy etc. but I'm entirely unable to avoid the error.

I'm unable to determine where `project-y` references `project-x` and how to correct this.

The only location where `project-[x|y]` are referenced is in `./sdk/setting/setting.yaml`:

```
defaultLocale: en
localizedSettings:
  developerEmail:
  developerName:
  displayName: Updates sample
  fullDescription:
  privacyPolicyUrl:
  pronunciation: Updates sample
  shortDescription:
  smallLogoImage:
  termsOfServiceUrl:
projectId: project-y
```

When I `gactions push` and `gactions preview deploy`, both commands correctly reference `project-y` and the generated URLs correctly point to `project-y`:

```sh
gactions push
Pushing files in the project "project-y" to Actions Console. This may take a few minutes.
Sending configuration files...

gactions deploy preview
Deploying files in the project "project-y" to Actions Console for preview. This may take a few minutes.
Sending configuration files...
```

I've scoured the `gactions` config and the cloned directory for hidden configuration files but am unable to find any references to `project-x`.

If I search, the only reference I find is the single reference to `project-y` in the above YAML.

[image: Actions Console: Test]

Comment: That does seem odd. Can you provide a screen shot to show where you're getting the error message and possibly what you're doing at the time? (Masking out sensitive info.) Any additional context might help.

Comment: @Prisoner thanks for the reply. The screenshot is in the question. I see the warning in the simulator when testing (after `gactions deploy preview`). It's been happening for a couple of days and across multiple projects. yesterday, I was receiving the same error when using `project-x` and it referenced `project-z` (not real project IDs) that I'd been using the day before that.

Comment: @Prisoner I'm having the same exact error for a project I just deleted. Did you have any luck so far?

Comment: It continues to occur for me and repro's across various projects that I've deleted. I learned today that the simulator includes requests|responses to webhooks but this doesn't include URL or header details and I've been unable to glean the requests from the logs so it remains difficult (not possible?) to debug

Comment: Please check my post below for the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389726/the-test-may-not-have-the-latest-project-changes-try-again-later

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the same issue.
In my case, it is because I used the same Display name for project-x and project-y.
I hope you check your project's Display name on Develop tab in Actions Console and solve your issue.